# How can OTC scams affect you?

Tags: scams, penny-stocks, pink-sheets

I learned a hard lesson today, and fortunately it wasn't that bad.

I invested a few thousand dollars in a penny stock carelessly (via ETRADE, with the intention of doing a short term trade, or a day trade if it proved worth it), without doing my research, and within a few hours (after the market closed), was punching myself in the face for being so stupid.

The company is Quantum International Corp (QUAN), and after doing my research I realized they have no product, no employees besides the CEO, and seem to be nothing more than a website asking for investments and promising huge returns. The CEO has a history of founding companies that promised a global name brand and never delivered so much as a brochure. The "news report" that made me buy the stock, passed down along BusinessWire, was nothing more than a fake press release by said CEO.

I know. It was insanely stupid. It will *never* happen again.

I had heard there were scammers among the OTC stocks, but somehow I didn't believe it.

And now I have this (ridiculous?) paranoid fear that I somehow won't be able to sell my stocks tomorrow morning, that somehow it'll prove impossible and my money will "vanish."

Am I being absurd? Should I be worrying? If I sell in the morning, I've only lost a couple hundred dollars, and learned a valuable lesson. Is there any reason to believe it won't be that simple?

Comment: For future reference, check out [this question](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/18849/7590) and its answers on how to avoid schemes like this. I know you've learned your lesson, but hopefully anyone else who finds this thread will see that thread as well.

Comment: @Aerovistae - I removed my comment, you are right. Not helpful, apologies.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer It's no problem, I do that too now and then. Sometimes people say/do such incredibly stupid things it's hard not to shout. Trust me, the things I was saying to myself were far worse. Retrospective self-astonishment, let's call it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Am I being absurd?

No.

> Should I be worrying?

Yes.

> If I sell in the morning, I've only lost a couple hundred dollars, and
>   learned a valuable lesson. Is there any reason to believe it won't be
>   that simple?

If you're lucky, you'll be able to dump your stocks to someone like you who'll be punching himself in the face tomorrow night. If not - you're stuck. You may end up selling them to your broker as worthless.

You might have become a victim of a "[pump and dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pump_and_Dump)" fraud. Those are hard to identify in real-time, but after been burned like that myself (for much lesser amounts than you though), I avoid any "penny" stocks that go up for no apparent (and verifiable) reason. In fact, I avoid them altogether.

Comment: That is a terrifying way to learn a lesson.

Comment: Never buy anything with quantum in its name. Each era has its own buzz words, and this time it seems to be nano and quantum. :D

Comment: Honestly that is valid advice which I had previously independently considered.

Comment: At least Quantum was a viable hard drive manufacturer, which was bought by Maxtor some time, long ago.

Comment: @joe which is now defunct and assimilated into Seagate because resistance is futile.

Comment: Penny stocks in general are at a high risk of both being de-listed and of pump and dump, as well as being very illiquid. Wost case is they become worthless, as they'll eventually fall to their real value of zero.